# Unknown provider, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What could I be doing wrong? I want to show some values but can't seem to get it to work. I tried using a constant and nothing's working.

Here are some snippets:

### values.js

```
angular.module('myApp').value('appSettings', {
    title: 'Customers Application',
    version: '1.0'
});

/*angular.module('myApp').constant('appSettings', {
    title: 'Customers Application',
    version: '1.0'
});*/
```

### customersController.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('CustomersController', function ($scope, customerFactory, appSettings) { 
    'use strict';

    $scope.sortBy = 'name';
    $scope.reverse = false;
    $scope.customers = [];
    $scope.appSettings = appSettings; 

    function init (){
        $scope.customers = customerFactory.getCustomers();
    }

    init();

    $scope.doSort = function (propName) {
        $scope.sortBy = propName;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});
```

### customers.html

```
<h3> {{ appSettings.title }}</h3>
Filter: <input type="text" ng-model="customerFilter.name" />
<br/><br/>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-click="doSort('name')">Name</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort('city')">City</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort('orderTotal')">Order Total</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort('joined')">Joined</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="cust in filtered = (customers | filter:customerFilter | orderBy:sortBy:reverse)">
        <td>{{ cust.name | uppercase }}</td>
        <td>{{ cust.city }}</td>
        <td>{{ cust.orderTotal | currency:'PLN' }}</td>
        <td>{{ cust.joined | date}}</td>
        <td><a href="#/orders/{{ cust.id }}">View Orders</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<span> Total customers: {{ filtered.length }} </span>
<br/>
<footer>Version: {{ appSettings.version }}</footer>
```

JS Console:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: appSettingsProvider <- appSettings <- CustomersController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/unpr?p0=appSettingsProvider%20%3C-%20appSettings%20%3C-%20CustomersController
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:68:12)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:4284:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:4432:39)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:4289:45
    at getService (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:4432:39)
    at invoke (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:4464:13)
    at Object.instantiate (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:4481:27)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:9108:28
    at $route.link (http://localhost:8080/angular-route.js:977:26)
    at invokeLinkFn (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:8746:9) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Any idea what my provider is "unknown"? This is my second day learning Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've pasted here, it's valid. Are you sure you're loading `values.js`?

Comment: how can i be sure i'm loading `values.js`?

Comment: Depends on how your application looks like. A good start would be the `Network` and `Sources` panels in Chrome Dev tools.

Comment: well network and sources don't show anything useful other than timelines and i'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Do you have an `index.html` where you include all your scripts? Look in that file, and make sure you've included `values.js`.

Comment: works! i'm following a tutorial that didn't include that the `values.js` script in the `index.html` thank you :)

Comment: Im taking the same course and Im having the exact same issue. Glad I found this!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure it causes the error you received, but one problem with the code you pasted is the use of angular.module(). The first time you use this function, call it with two parameters: the name, and an array of any module dependencies. So whichever file is loaded first should say something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
```

Comment: You would get a `Module 'myApp' is not available error` if this was the case though.